# How do I create a border over div with content?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have to create a div over which there is a 3px border, and this boundary is positioned over the content in the div, how can I do this without knowing the size of the block?
An example is in the image below:

[image: chartist image]

My code: https://codepen.io/pen/yLObXvv

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="case-study">
        <div class="case-study-image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551434678-e076c223a692?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="Intro image"/>
        </div>
        <div class="case-study-content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #04142d;
}
.case-study {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #0E53DD;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.case-study-image {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
.case-study-image img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 20rem;
    object-fit: cover;
    oject-position: 0 0;
}
.case-study-content {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code to help us answer your question?

Comment: @sven yes, I've added an example here: https://codepen.io/pen/yLObXvv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Use CSS ::after Selector with position: absolute**

The coordinates of an absolute positioned element are relative to its parent. It is positioned automatically to the starting point (top-left corner) of its parent element.

```css
body {
    background-color: #04142d;
}
.case-study {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: #0E53DD;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    position:relative;
    max-width:500px;
}
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
.case-study-image {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
.case-study-image img {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 20rem;
    object-fit: cover;
    oject-position: 0 0;
}
.case-study-content {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.case-study:after {
    content: '';
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height: calc(100% - 6px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    right: -10px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-study">
  <div class="case-study-image"> <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551434678-e076c223a692?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" class="img-fluid" alt="Intro image"/> </div>
  <div class="case-study-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>style</title>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px
            background-color:white;
        }

        .move {
            transform: (30px, 180px)
            background: transparent;
            border: 3px solid red;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="move"></div>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use this and try to style it the way you want